# Using Custom .NET Code with DOTNETNUKE

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I'm currently doing some research for a website design company who wants me to take a look into DOTNETNUKE and some of it's capabilities.  One of their questions is: Can you use custom .NET code in DNN?  If so, how?

The only examples I've seen of this so far are located in the "Desktop Modules/Admin" directory and these all appear to be controls.  In order to utilize .NET code, do you have to make a control or can .NET methods be called to directly from DNN?

Comment: what do you want to use DNN for?

Comment: they are considering it as an option for a prospective customer... this customer is requiring them to offer a CMS with the website they are building

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create DotNetNuke modules which integrate with the DNN infrastructure (i.e. you can specify authorization rights for your modules so that only certain roles or users can see them). Modules support versioning, and packaging (as a .zip file), and automatic execution of delta database scripts to simplify deployment. There is an overhead in learning the module development process though.

You can view the quick start guide here - http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DotNetNuke-6-Developer-Quick-Start.aspx

You can purchase third-party custom modules here - http://store.dotnetnuke.com/

[XMod](http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-details/xmod-55---forms-views-and-lists) is a popular module that you can purchase to ease any custom development. It has it's own process for creating custom forms/templates etc which can produce faster results than developing your own modules.

Comment: They aren't so concerned about making custom .NET controls as much as running custom .NET code.  I believe they are looking to be able to pass parameters into .NET methods and get the return value.

Comment: You can include ASP.NET code inside your DNN skins, or if you want a configurable module that has an edit screen etc, then you need to create a DNN module, so both are possible with DNN. You might also want to consider Umbraco. Umbraco 5 is out which is built around MVC, rather than the aging Web Forms platform.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to write your own .NET code and use it in combo with DotNetNuke:

1. It's open source, so from [the download page](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Downloads.aspx) you can grab the source and start from there. Not entirely sure how the licensing is if you do this.
2. From the same [download page](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Downloads.aspx) go to the Visual Studio Starter Kit. With it you can create modules (and skins) that can contain controls and pages which you can use in your DotNetNuke portals.

Of course you can also create a custom HttpModule that routes default traffic to your DotNetNuke app, and some traffic to different (custom .NET) code altogether.